# Constraints not working in UITableviewCells through storyboard, the content is always left aligned with respect to the main view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, ios-autolayout

I have a label in my table cell which has some static content and it needs to be center aligned with respect to its main view. The constraints are horizontally and vertically in container. But when i run the app then the label is always left aligned no matter what constraints i am applying to it. Moreover if i align the label to the right with the trailing and top constraint, it still remains to the left. If i remove all the constraints of label then it works perfect for all the screen sizes. Not able to get to the actual issue. Can someone please help me with the actual issue. (Using Xcode 8.3.3)

Comment: update your question with screenshots

Comment: Please do add some UI explanation to understand your question to others.

Answer (score -1):

give this a try .

Select your tableView cell and go the attributes inspector and do the settings as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

Accept answer if it helps you and leave your comment. good luck.